# xcode 4 svn issue, commits fail with “The operation could not be performed no repositories could be reached.”

Tags: svn, xcode4

Yet another xcode 4 svn issue, commits fail with “The operation could not be performed no repositories could be reached.” 
This is for a project that is newly checked out from a remote svn repository an edit is made to a file and trying to commit the change fails because the xcode 4’s “brain dead” svn integration fails. In xcode I can diff the file with previous versions, see the complete history… Commit from the shell works fine. Having run into 8 separate issues dealing with connectivity with svn repositories in xcode I have reached a level of extreme frustration. From my perspective this portion of xcode is totally untested and bug ridden. Any help on this hopefully (but doubtful) last issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

According to this [Apple thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3375258?start=0&tstart=0), this seems to be a bug waiting a fix from Apple (Xcode 4.2 and Lion 10.7.2).

[image: XCode repo could not be reached]

Some mention an issue with self-signed certificates, other reports it isn't working with an `svn://` protocol either.

> Open Safari, navigate to your online repo.
>   When it will complain against self-signed SSL, click view certificate, then check Allways trust...
>   You will be prompted for keychain access, comply.
>   Restart Xcode, your repo should be online.

Only current workaround for non-ssl retated issue:

> Instead of using the Project Navigator, use the Organizer:
>
> 1. Choose the folder containing the project you checked out of your svn repository.
> 2. At the bottom of the Organizer window, click on the "Commit" icon.
> 3. Select the files you want to check in and add your comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you've tried to access the repo via a IP address, you can try to map the address to a domain name in /etc/hosts, then create a repo in XCode using the domain name and try again. Good Luck!