# SVN repository in Xcode, troubleshooting tips

Tags: iphone, xcode, svn

So I have two works computer, one that I use mainly for development, the other Macbook is pretty slow so I rarely use it.  I'm new to the whole subversion / source control thing as this is my first development job.  My lead does not the answer to this either so I thought I'd try to get some help here on SO.  We are trying to connect to a repository that is on one of our consultant's servers.  On my main computer, I have no problem connecting to it and committing and updating files.  I never have problems.

At one point, I was able to connect through Xcode and get updates (this might have been before I upgraded to Lion and the newest Xcode), but something must have gotten messed up and I do not know why I cannot connect to the repository.  When I try, I get the error:

> **The operation could not be performed no repositories could be reached.**  Please verify that one or more repositories are online and
>   reachable and try again.

I have tried cleaning the project, resetting Xcode, resetting the computer and I continue to get this message.  So I tried getting the files again in a new directory on my computer, with the command:

```
svn co https://urladdress ./NewFolder/
```

The download works, EXCEPT the files are from two weeks ago.  I can't grab any of the latest updates.  Any thoughts on how I can fix this problem?  There are 3 other computers total that have no problem connecting to this repository.  Thanks!

Comment: Check out  this post.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975791/xcode-4-svn-issue-commits-fail-with-the-operation-could-not-be-performed-no-re

Comment: @Rayfleck can you put your comment as an answer so I can give you credit!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XCode has a lot of bugs with SVN.  There are some workaround in this post:
  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975791/xcode-4-svn-issue-commits-fail-with-the-operation-could-not-be-performed-no-re)